# Why getting error 00933: sql command improperly ended?

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I keep getting error 00933: statement improperly ended for this query. I cannot figure out why it is happening. This is an Oracle database and I'm using TOAD. The problem lies with the "Insert" statement; if I only run the code after the insert statement, it works. Thanks in advance.

```
Insert into uscg_awdattachment_request columns(seq, uscgextractkey)
select tooth.seq, 1 group_num
from(
select b.seq, b.uncompressed, a.docnum, b.dockey, b.verkey, b.filename, b.storedfileblob, b.updatetimestamp, row_number() over(partition by a.dockey order by b.updatetimestamp asc) as obs_no
  from (select c.*
         from prism.supportdoc c) b 
         left join prism.header a
         on a.dockey = b.dockey and a.verkey = b.verkey) tooth
where tooth.obs_no = 1;
```

Update: According to the internet, you cannot use joins with insert statements. I need to find another way to join the two tables without the "join" syntax.

Comment: remove `columns` from `Insert into uscg_awdattachment_request columns(seq, uscgextractkey)`

Comment: That's not the problem; still getting error

Comment: How are you running it? You might just need to remove the semicolon from the end; it's a statement separator so it's sometimes allowed and relevant, and sometimes, not allowed and causes this error, or ORA-00911. (`columns` is just a confusing table alias name...)

Comment: "you cannot use joins with insert statement" - that's true with a direct join as part of the `insert` part; but your join is within the `select` part, [which works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=45e8ed0c8126043b5c1fd6d891440c37) (but can be simplified to get rid of a subquery, at least...). So the problem is Toad or how you are running it - see previous comment; did you try without the semicolon?

Comment: Yep, stil did not work without semicolon

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tested the statement using SQL*Plus ?
2. If SQL*Plus works then it maybe a TOAD issue - ind that case try to create a stored procedure and execute it
3. Small testcase with required table description required to progress !!